# Запрос на выборку товаров с минимальной ценой по каждому id товара

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть таблица, в которой для каждого товара есть несколько значений.

Пример таблицы:

```
id | number | price
1  |   3    | 22.3
2  |   1    | 34.3
3  |   3    | 42.4
4  |   1    | 44.3
5  |   4    | 21.3
```

Сейчас запрос имеет вид:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE number IN (3,1,4)
```

Нужно сделать запрос на выборку товаров с минимальной ценой по каждому `number`. Как я понимаю: нужно просто сделать сортировку от минимального к максимальному и поставить лимит на каждый `number`.

**Используем**: MYSQL, PHP + CI3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.*
FROM
  table t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    number,
    MIN(price) minPrice
  FROM
    table
  GROUP BY
    number
) t2
  ON
    t1.number = t2.number
    AND t1.price = t2.minPrice
```

Во вложенном запросе мы для каждого номера выбираем минимальную цену. Потом делаем `INNER JOIN` этой выборки на нашу таблицу, и таким образом получаем информацию о каждом товаре, у которого минимальная цена в своей категории.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f110e/3

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Зачем выбирать min(price)? мне нужен только товар с минимальной ценой. Т.е. через WHERE IN я выбираю несколько товаров с одинаковым number, а мне нужен только один товар с минимальной.

Comment: Понял. Сейчас переделаю запрос.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен)

Comment: @ka5itoshka готово

Comment: Вроде бы понятно) Спасибо!)